# Cause of "strict refs" error

Tags: perl

I have a strange problem with one object (which extends superobjects fyi)

Variable $self is already blessed by a superclass and can be normally dumped.
I have a dozens packages with the same setter/getter logic, and all have 'use stricts'.
This one yields me an error on a return of one of them, and would like to get rid of it.
The error is:

```
Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"
```

on the return `$self->{"_table"}` line.

Why this same-as-other code acts different ?

If I do check for a class object before, the message is gone.

```
/* Constructor*/
sub new {
...
   Width($self, delete($def->{"width"})) ;   # $self is created before already
   Table($self,$table) ;   
...
}

sub Width
{
   my ($self,$ width) = @_ ;
   $self->{"_width"} = $width if $width ;
   return $self->{"_width"} ;
}

/* WORKING CODE VERSION*/
sub Table
{
   my ($self, $table)=@_ ;
   return unless $self ;
   $self->{"_table"} = $table if $table ;
   return $self->{"_table"} ;
}

/* WARNING CODE VERSION*/
sub Table
{
   my ($self, $table)=@_ ;
   $self->{"_table"} = $table if $table ;
   return $self->{"_table"} ;           <<<<<< STRICT ERROR
}
```

Comment: what have you done in the function delete($def->{"width"}), it may change the $self structure. Please check it. You use unless in the check does it really return the value of $self->{"_table"}?

Comment: Are you including **both** `use strict` and `use warnings`? If not, give that a try and see if you get more information.

Comment: If you want even more information you can add `use diagnostics` http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html

Comment: By the way, `$self->Table($table)` makes far more sense than `Table($self,$table)`.

Comment: - delete() is perl internal, it undefines the variable if defined but returns its value, i use this to remove parameters, so the Carp... on the end is issued for warning of invalid parameters
- thanks for hints on diagnostics and warnings, actually in 15yrs i never used it :P
- Table method otherwise works properly

Comment: With diagnostics and warnings on, I use same result.

I added a debug just before return... line and it shows ok:

    `Called from Window.pm line 41: ref($self)=Window ref($self->{_table})=Table`

(Window is a class, so $self is ok, and $self->{_table} holds a Table class object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did `Table("", ...)` or `Table(undef, ...)` somewhere. (The latter would also give a warning.)

Comment: in `sub new` probably. I bet the "..." doesn't include setting `$self` to something sensible.

Comment: $self is an object created by the supperclass, and the dump of it is ok

Comment: You were right, I really did clearing a table with Table("") :P